# Migrating Polymer Tutorial from 0.5 to 1.0

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to migrate this example https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/start/tutorial/intro.html to version 1.0.

It's almost done but I have two issues:

First, how can I reference a property of an element in a selector for styling?

```
:host([favorite]) paper-icon-button {
  color: #da4336;
}
```

this doesn't seem to work however property is declared like this:

```
<script>
Polymer({
  is: "post-card",
  properties: {
    favorite: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false,
      notify: true
    }
  },
    favoriteTapped: function(e) {
        this.favorite = !this.favorite;
        this.fire('favorite-tap');
    }
});
```

Full source code is here: https://github.com/zjor/polymer-tutorial/blob/master/post-card.html

Second, does expressions work the same way as in 0.5?
E.g.

```
        <post-card 
      favorite="{{item.favorite}}" 
      on-favorite-tap="handleFavorite" 
      hidden?="{{show == 'favorites' && !item.favorite}}">
```

Doesn't work either. Source: https://github.com/zjor/polymer-tutorial/blob/master/post-list.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question, set `reflectToAttribute` to `true` in your properties declaration.

```
properties: {
    favorite: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false,
        reflectToAttribute: true,
        notify: true
    }
},
```

As for the second question, complex expressions have been removed in 1.0 (see [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#expressions-in-binding-annotations)). You will need to use [computed bindings](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#annotated-computed). Also, the syntax has been changed from ? to $.

```
hidden$="{{compute(show, item.favorite)}}">
```

Comment: Thanks! It works like magic! I've pushed final fixes to github.